# What is one-session short presentation or lecture in CV?

Tags: cv, lecturer, workshop

In during the M.Sc., when complex networks course lectured by prof. in university, he said me that I will talk about complex networks and my B.Sc. thesis in one session for students.

How to can I write it in my CV? What is it? a lecture? presentation? or workshop?

> It was a lecture of Introduction to Complex Networks in the Complex Networks course for master of science (M.SC.) students. Also, I lectured about the Graph, R, and iGraph package in R programming language.

Comment: Lecture. Such an item might help the "Teaching Activities" part of a CV. You may choose to leave it out, depending on who will be reading the CV.